# Bind Same Seam Class to different Context Variables

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a state class. I need two new state objects in session scope to be injected in two of my controllers. Whenever mycontroller is created, I want the state objected to be instantiated. When I use the syntax below, I get the same state object injected in both the controllers.

I want something equivalent to

```
session.setAttribute("myFirstControllerState", myScreenStateObj1);
session.setAttribute("mySecondControllerState", myScreenStateObj2);


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@AutoCreate
@Name("myScreenState")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)

public class MyScreenState implements Serializable {

}

@AutoCreate
@Name("myFirstScreenController")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class MyFirstController implements Serializable {
   @In(value="myScreenState")
   @Out(value="myScreenState")
   private MyScreenState myFirstControllerState;
}

@AutoCreate
@Name("mySecondScreenController")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class MySecondController implements Serializable {

    @In(value="myScreenState")
    @Out( value="myScreenState")
    private MyScreenState mySecondControllerState;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Add @Roles annotation to the state class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@AutoCreate
@Name("myScreenState")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Roles({@Role(name="myState1", scope=ScopeType.PAGE),  
    @Role(name="myState2",scope=ScopeType.PAGE)})

public class MyScreenState implements Serializable {

}
```

In controllers just use

```
private MyScreenState myState1;
```